# single or multiple tables in database?

Tags: database

My system collects a lot of data from different resources (each resource has text-ID), and send it to client bounded together in predefined groups.  there some hundreds of different resources, each might set record in period of second up some hours.  there less then hundred "view groups".

The data collector is single-threaded.

what is the best method to organize the data?
a. make different table for each source, where the name of the table is based on the source id?
b. make single table and add the source id as text-field (key if possible)?
c. table for each predefined display group, with the source id as text-field?

- each record has value (float) and date (date).  the query will be something like select * from ... where date < d1 and date > d2.  In case of single table, it will be "and sourceId in(...)"

database type is unknown yet, it might be lightsql, postgres, mysql, mssql ...

Comment: One table is usually the right solution.  Databases are designed to handle large tables, but not necessary many, many different tables.

Comment: Moreover, you can make queries considering different resource_id (eg. COUNT(*) of all events for each resource_id,...)